# error : "/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")" when I want to build my lib with my makefile

Tags: c, linux, gcc, makefile

when I want to compile my lib with my makefile I get this error. It is caused by this "ifeq". What I would like to do here is to write : "⏳ compiling libft" the first time a ".o" is created. the first time "$<" is equal to "srcs/char/ft_isalpha.c", the condition must just do if ($< == "srcs/char/ft_isalpha.c"). But I don't know how to do this in a makefile.

rule that breaks

```
%.o: %.c ${HEADER}
    ifeq ($<, srcs/char/ft_isalpha.c)
        @echo "⏳ compiling libft"
    @$(CC) -I ${CFLAGS} -c $< -o $@
```

error:

```
ifeq (srcs/char/ft_isalpha.c, srcs/char/ft_isalpha.c)
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
make: *** [Makefile:107: srcs/char/ft_isalpha.o] Error 2
```

I tried to modifies the syntax but it didn't worked. It seems correct for me but apparently not.

Comment: `ifeq` must not be indented, and so is `endif`, which you forgot. `@echo` should be indented by a single tab (I forgot whether 2+ tabs work, but if they do, the extra tabs have no effect). `,` in `ifeq` must not have a space after it, it will be included in the equality check.

Comment: You cannot, of course, write an `ifeq` statement that checks `$<` because `ifeq` is a _preprocessor_ statement that is parsed at makefile read-in time, and `$<` is an automatic variable which is not set until the rule is built.

Comment: thank you for your answer. but i found another way that seems better because no matter what the name of the first file it works in all cases. `PRINT_COMPILE = @echo "compiling"

%.o: %.c
 $(PRINT_COMPILE)
 $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
 @$(eval PRINT_COMPILE = @:)`